# ionic; javascript return after .then

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, chain

communicating with a REST service in ionic, I'ld like to have functions similar to this

```
function ListCategories_Request(){
   rqst=_BuildRequest("ListCategories");
   rqst.Data={extraParam1:1,
              extraParam2:2
             }
   return $http({...ValidParameters including the rqst...}).then(GetResult,Request_onError)
}
```

For each function of the REST-Service, I would build a similar java-script function.

Now, as the sent request is unique, the received result needs to be handled unique, too. The REST-Service-Based analysis of the result is added to the .then-chain, but updating the parent class and the UI needs to happen in the parent class.

So, I would like to do calls like

```
ListCategories_Request().then(function(res){ UpdateCategories()});
ListFrames_Request().then(function(res){ UpdateFrames()});
```

The current problem is, that UpdateCategories() is called, before the result of the http-Request is analysed.

So, how do I prevent return $http(...).then(GetResult,OnError) to return, before the specific function inside GetResult is called?

Code of GetResult:

```
function GetResult( res){
        if(res.status==200)
        {
            if( (res.data!=={}) && (res.data.Data!=={}) )
            {
                  return AnalyzeResult(res.data);
            }
        }
    };
```

While AnalyzeResult is like:

```
        function AnalyzeResult(Result)
    {
            Func=Result.Func;
            switch(Func.toUpperCase())
            {
                case "LISTCATEGORIES":
                    erg = ListCategories_Result(Result);
                    break;
                case "LISTFRAMES":
                    erg= ListFrames_Result(Result);
                    break;
                default:
                    erg = {};
                    console.log("UnKnown Result!");
            }
            FinalizeRequest(Index);
        }
        return erg;
    }
```

So, I do not really get, where my mistake is. How do I prevent ListCategories_Request or ListFrames_Request from returning too early?

Thank you and best regards

Frank

Comment: are ListCategories_???? functions asynchronous? Do they return a *thenable*? Is FinalizeRequest asynchronous? Do you need to wait for that to complete? do you realise `erg` is global?

Comment: I think you need promises

Comment: @Ladmerc the below answer proposes promises.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using $q (given you are using angular anyway via ionic). That way you can use promises to do what you want to do. Here's an example that I put together to demonstrate the idea:

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp",[]);
app.controller("TestController", function($scope, $http, $q){
  $scope.message = "Deferred Example";
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  function getAllPosts(extractor) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(function(data){
          console.log("Data is: ", data);
          $scope.postIds = extractor(data.data);
          deferred.resolve($scope.postIds);
       });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function extractPostIds(data) {
    console.log("Exracting the data: ", data);
    return data.map(function(post){
      return post.id;
    })
  }

  function squarePostIds(postIds) {
    console.log("Squaring post ids: ", postIds);
    $scope.squaredPostIds = postIds.map(function(id){ return id*id;});
  }

  getAllPosts(extractPostIds)
    .then(function(postIds){ 
        squarePostIds(postIds);
    });
});
```

And here's the JSBin for this: https://jsbin.com/fugeyad/3/edit?html,js,output

Update: Adding some links to read about promises.

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/